# iPod classic battery life

Tags: battery, ipod-classic

I have an iPod classic and tend to keep it plugged into a mains charger while playing music up to 4 hours a day.  Will doing this damage the battery?  Is it better to use all the battery power and then fully recharge it each time?  Perhaps somewhere inbetween the two options above?

And when the battery finally gives up the ghost, can I still use my iPod by plugging it into the mains charger and running it off the mains rather than the battery?

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but a fair comparison...

I have a 10-year old iPod [iPod photo, I think] that lives in my car glove-box, hooked up to power & connectivity on my car audio system. It only gets used when I'm driving. When I'm not out & about it gets no power, sometimes up to 2 weeks at a time. I bring it into the house & update it from iTunes every month or so.
Don't know how much longer it may last, nor have I ever tested how long the battery charge may last if used unpowered, but it's been no prob so far for my usage needs.

Based on current wisdom [google for refs, too many to list, idk if any of them are true or just copied the info from another site], it would appear to be best to keep the battery at somewhere between 50% & 80% charge.
Leaving it plugged in shouldn't damage the battery, as the charger system is smart enough to not allow that - but I don't know how that would affect overall battery life.

As mentioned above, mine gets charged when I'm in the car, sometimes goes weeks between charges, sometimes it's on 8 hours a day.
So far, all is still well.